# Is telling someone to wait basically the same as telling them to stop? And the other way around?

Tags: word-choice

I know that stop can be a synonym for wait,btw. I know telling someone to wait means for someone to pause until a certain time. But telling someone to stop just means the person has to pause without a defined amount of time to resume (I hope this makes me sound smart haha). Here are some examples:

"Wait! I want to tell you more."

Would it be the same saying-

"Stop! I want to tell you more. "

I want to note, that I am a native speaker. I'm just a curious person and a thinker. :-)

Comment: What contexts do you expect before and after 'wait!'? What contexts for 'stop!'? Are they similar? Are they identical?

Comment: @Mitch oh! I didn't think about that. I'll fixed it in a few minutes

Comment: I'm actually not very sure what context to put so I'm going to say...same context.

Comment: Clearly they are not direct synonyms. The verb *stop* issued as an imperative demands that something that is happening be stopped. However *wait* does not necessarily imply that anything is happening, but just demands that an interval of time be allowed to elapse before something happens. Obviously one can think of circumstances where the two words could become synonymous, but there are plenty more where they cannot.

Comment: Well, I did know they weren't direct synonyms. I was thinking when someone tells another person to "wait" the first person  pretty much wants the other person to stop what they are doing until a certain time. So, I was thinking if a person tells you to stop, it has same effect as saying wait :)

Comment: It's entirely dependent on context and emphasis.

Comment: Stop, wait! No, wait... stop!

Answer (score 1):

"Wait" implies an intention of allowing or encouraging a later resumption of the activity being (temporarily) halted.  "Stop" includes no such implication.  "Stop" can be permanent or not.

I would not consider them to be synonyms, and they are not "basically the same".

Comment: ok I get it. I hope I'm not going to get told off too badly. @Tim D

Answer (score 1):

In contemporary speech, *Wait* is sometimes used in a dialogue as a signal that the speaker wants to comment on what the other person just said. It can be thought of as a truncated version of [*wait a moment*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/wait-a-minute-moment-second). The form [*Wait, what!?*](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=wait%20what) is also used to indicate surprise or incredulity.

On the other hand, *Stop* on its own is a conversation halter unless it is coupled with an invitation to continue, e.g. *Stop, back up. What did you mean ...* .

In practice, other than the case of *Stop* as a conversation halter, there is little difference in usage between the two except that *Stop* can be considered a more forceful version of *Wait*.